# Writing a custom auth system (like the default django auth system), use it to generate tables in DB

Tags: django, authentication, model

Hay all, I've been reading up on middleware and how to use it with a context object. I want to write a simple middleware class which i can use on my own applications, it will essentially be a cut down version of the django one.

The problem i seem to have is that if i have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('django.contrib.my_auth')
```

in the settings file, all is well. I've also added

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ('django.contrib.my_auth.middleware.MyAuthMiddleware')
```

in it and everything is fine.

My question is, how would i make my middleware automatically generate tables from a models.py module, much like how the django auth does when i run manage.py syncdb?

thanks

Comment: You shouldn't put your own code into django.contrib. Keep it separate.

Comment: Point take, it now resides in my project folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django auth middleware doesn't generate any tables. Django does it looking through INSTALLED_APPS when you run manage.py syncdb. Therefore all should already be fine.

Comment: so 'django.contrib.my_auth.models' should get run when i run manage.py syncdb